# 32 bit architectures no longer supported - how to fix?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.Forms PCL app for iOS. I tried to change its deployment target to 11.3 (in info.plist) but got an error:

> This project is configured to support 32 bit architectures, which are
>   no longer supported from iOS 11. It can be changed on the iOS Build
>   properties page.

When I check the iOS Build tab in the app's properties page (I'm using Visual Studio on Windows 10) I can't find anything for that.

**EDIT** (to the answer below): on iOS Build page:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change to the iOS Build Support arch to `x86_64` (simulator) only and `ARM64` (iPhone device) only.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I'm using Visual Studio (I now updated my question to include that) and I posted a screenshot of what I see there. So which one is the same as what you've posted?

Comment: OK. Never mind. Your updated answer made it clear that I should just choose ARM64. (In case I misunderstood, please let me know.)